# Determine what a sound snippet contains?

Tags: data, sound

The function `SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]` brings up an interface that lets you record a sound object. Let's say we first record a one second long snippet of background noise called `background`. Afterwards we record two short snippets `sn1` and `sn2` one of which again contains only the background noise, while the second one contains the sound of our voice. Is there any function in Mathematica which could use `background` as a gauge and tell us as computationally efficient as possible which of the two snippets contains the voice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. After recording the snippets and background using `SystemDialogInput["RecordSound"]`, send the sound objects through a `BandpassFilter` to restrict to voice frequencies only:

```
background =  BandpassFilter[background, {300, 3400}];
sn1 =  BandpassFilter[sn1, {300, 3400}];
sn2 =  BandpassFilter[sn2, {300, 3400}];
```

Then we can see if the maximum amplitude in either of the snippets is higher than the one in `background`:

```
mback=Max[Abs[background /. Sound[{SampledSoundList[x_, y_]}]-> x]];
msn1=Max[Abs[sn1 /. Sound[{SampledSoundList[x_, y_]}]-> x]];
msn2=Max[Abs[sn2 /. Sound[{SampledSoundList[x_, y_]}]-> x]];
thresh=5;
If[msn1/mback>thresh,Print["sn1 is voice"],Print["sn1 no voice"]]
If[msn2/mback>thresh,Print["sn2 is voice"],Print["sn2 no voice"]]
```

Here the threshold was set to max amplitude of voice being at least `5` times bigger than background noise. I set it to this value, since on average my voice got a score of about `10` in this fraction.

Comment: I'd compare the total power in band rather than just the max amplitude. (Total power  = `Total[Abs[signal]^2])/Length@signal` It'll probably be a slightly better comparison, and you can express it in dB above background by taking `10*Log[voicePower/backgroundPower]`.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds better indeed!